# Dynamically calculating change to the nearest 10 dollars

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically calculate the change to the nearest 10 dollars.  For instance, the user inputs a value (34.36), my code then calculates tip, tax, and total amount for the bill (total 44.24).  Without user input, I need to calculate the change from $50.00.  I've tried to round up to 50.00 from 44.24 with no luck, obviously I am doing something wrong.  I've tried Math.round and tried to find the remainder using %.  Any help on how to get the total change due to the nearest 10 dollar value would be great.  Thank you in advance, below is my code:
Full dis-closer, this is a homework project.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class test1
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Get input from user
    System.out.println("Enter Bill Value:                   ");
    double x = sc.nextDouble();

    //Calculate the total bill
    double salesTax = .0875;
    double tipPercent = .2;
    double taxTotal = (x * salesTax);
    double tipTotal = (x * tipPercent);
    double totalWithTax = (x + taxTotal);
    double totalWithTaxAndTip = (x + taxTotal + tipTotal);

    //TODO:  Test Case 34.36...returns amount due to lower 10 number
    //This is where I am getting stuck                  
    double totalChange = (totalWithTaxAndTip % 10);




    //Format and display the results
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();

    //Build Message / screen output
    String message =
        "Bill Value:                         " + currency.format(x) + "\n" + 
        "Tax Total:                          " + currency.format(taxTotal) + "\n" +
        "Total with Tax:                     " + currency.format(totalWithTax) + "\n" +
        "20 Percent Tip:                     " + currency.format(tipTotal) + "\n" +
        "Total with Tax and 20 Percent Tip:  " + currency.format(totalWithTaxAndTip) + "\n" +
        "Total Change:                       " + currency.format(totalChange) + "\n";

    System.out.println(message);

}
}
```

Comment: Nearest multiplier of 10 dollars from 44.24 is 40, isn't it?

Comment: convert to int - divide by 10 - add 1 - convert back to double

Comment: When working with Money in programming, it is often better represented in an int as 'cents'. 1 dollar = 100 stored in an int. When you output the value, just divide and mod by 100 and output the decimal as appropriate. This avoids rounding issues that happen with float/double.

Comment: @Sam I am - If the change amount is $20.00 exactly, your approach would result in $30.

Comment: "calculate the change to the nearest 10 dollars": I guess you don't want the nearest, but the "nearest 10 dollars value that is greater than the total sum you have"

Comment: totalChange = totalWithTaxAndTip - (totalWithTaxAndTip % 10)

Comment: @JLRishe easily solved by checking whether you have an exact $10 amount before calculating change

Answer (score 1):

you make
           `double totalChange = round((totalWithTaxAndTip / 10)) * 10;`

Comment: I think the OP wants to to always round up, but I'll leave it to him to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Math.ceil(double) will round up a number. So what you need is something like that:

```
 double totalChange = (int) Math.ceil(totalWithTaxAndTip / 10) * 10;
```

For totalWithTaxAndTip = 44.24, totalChange = 50.00

For totalWithTaxAndTip = 40.00, totalChange = 40.00

Answer (score 0):

Math.round rounds a number to the nearest whole number, so as others have shown, you need to divide by 10, then multiply by 10 after rounding:

```
double totalChange = tenderedAmount - totalWithTaxAndTip;

double totalChangeRounded  = 10 * Math.round(totalChange / 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone, thank you very much for helping me.  I tested out everyone's solution.  This is my final working code.....

```
double totalAmountPaid = totalWithTaxAndTip - (totalWithTaxAndTip % 10) + 10;
```

I tested it out using many different values and it seems to be working the way I want it to.

Again, I appreciate everyone for taking the time to help me out.